Having an issue with data populating into an HTML
I have a script that pulls data from multiple reports and outputting into an HTML report. The report builds successfully and when I try it with a single column the data outputs successfully. I'm thinking is that the column values need to be defined. When I output to multiple columns though I get zeros in all the columns. Additionally I have a blurb in the script that pulls the day the report was published from report.
# Define the output file path 
$outputFilePath = ".\report.html"

# Define the path to the file containing site codes
$siteCodesFile = ".\Site.txt"

# Define the path to the text file
$filePath = ".\20240405.txt"

# Read the site codes from the file
$siteCodes = Get-Content -Path $siteCodesFile

# Define the days of the week
$daysOfWeek = "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"

# Initialize counts for each site code and each day of the week
$siteCodeDayCounts = @{}
foreach ($siteCode in $siteCodes) {
    $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode] = @{}
    foreach ($day in $daysOfWeek) {
        $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode][$day] = @{
            "Good" = 0
            "Bad" = 0
        }
    }
}

# Read the content of the text file
$content = Get-Content -Path $filePath

# Retrieve the day from the report
$reportDay = $content[1] -replace ".*Sent:\s*|\s*,.*"
Write-Host "Report Day: $reportDay"

# Loop through each line in the content
foreach ($line in $content) {
    # Loop through each site code
    foreach ($siteCode in $siteCodes) {
        # Loop through each day of the week
        foreach ($day in $daysOfWeek) {
            # Use the -match operator to check if the line contains the site code followed by the day and "functional" or "pending"
            if ($line -match "$siteCode.*$day.*(functional|Pending)") {
                $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode][$day].Good++
            }
            # Use the -match operator to check if the line contains the site code followed by the day and "not functional" or "unknown"
            if ($line -match "$siteCode.*$day.*(not functional|Unknown)") {
                $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode][$day].Bad++
            }
        }
    }
}

# Output the HTML
$htmlOutput = @"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Site Code Report</title>
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    th {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Site Code Report for $reportDay</h2>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Site Code</th>
"@

# Add table headers for each day of the week
foreach ($day in $daysOfWeek) {
    $htmlOutput += "<th>$day Good</th><th>$day Bad</th>"
}

$htmlOutput += @"
</tr>
"@

# Populate table rows with data for each site code
foreach ($siteCode in $siteCodes) {
    $htmlOutput += "<tr><td>$siteCode</td>"
    foreach ($day in $daysOfWeek) {
        $goodCount = $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode][$day]["Good"]
        $badCount = $siteCodeDayCounts[$siteCode][$day]["Bad"]
        $htmlOutput += "<td>$goodCount</td><td>$badCount</td>"
    }
    $htmlOutput += "</tr>"
}

$htmlOutput += @"
</table>
</body>
</html>
"@

# Output the HTML
$htmlOutput | Out-File -FilePath $outputFilePath -Encoding UTF8

Write-Host "HTML report generated successfully."


You might find the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet useful in this case. Just construct a PSCustomObject with the data you need and pipe to the cmdlet. The cmdlet will create the table for you.

If your $siteCodesFile is a csv you probably want $siteCodes = Import-Csv $siteCodesFile instead of $siteCodes = Get-Content -Path $siteCodesFile - that will let you treat the data as structured objected with individual properties instead of using -match on comma-separated strings…

It's a txt, changed it in the code not sure why it was pasted as a csv, issue still remains. Importing the sites was never the issue it does that perfectly.
